# Is it possible to create custom npm start command in package.json in Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I would like to achieve the situation where I can run both commands in npm:

```
npm start
npm startDev
```

I configured package.json this way

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "SET NODE_ENV=production & nodemon servis.js",
    "startdev": "nodemon servis.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3"
  }
}
```

Running **npm start** works fine, but when I type **npm startDev** I get

```
Usage: npm <command>
where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, bin, bugs, c, cache, completion, config,
    ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor, edit,
    explore, get, help, help-search, i, init, install,
    install-test, it, link, list, ln, login, logout, ls,
    outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix, profile, prune,
    publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root, run, run-script,
    s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star, stars, start, stop, t,
    team, test, token, tst, un, uninstall, unpublish, unstar,
    up, update, v, version, view, whoami
```

Comment: No, anything outside of the preset commands listed there you have to use `npm run startDev` or switch to Yarn.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being downvoted. It's a clear and specific question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bunch of `preset` commands such as [start](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start) defined in the documentation as :

> This runs an arbitrary command specified in the package's "start"
>   property of its "scripts" object. If no "start" property is specified
>   on the "scripts" object, it will run node server.js.

---

If you want to add a new command which is not a `preset`, like `startDev`, you can add it directly in the `package.json`, like you did :

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "SET NODE_ENV=production & nodemon servis.js",
    "startdev": "nodemon servis.js"
  },
}
```

But to run it you would have to use [npm run](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)

> This runs an arbitrary command from a package's "scripts" object. If
>   no "command" is provided, it will list the available scripts.
>   run[-script] is used by the test, start, restart, and stop commands,
>   but can be called directly, as well. When the scripts in the package
>   are printed out, they're separated into lifecycle (test, start,
>   restart) and directly-run scripts.

---

**Example** :

```
npm run startdev
```